# Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 + mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php

Warning: `mysql_result()` expects parameter `1` to be resource, boolean given in on line `27`.

Вот 27 строка:

```
$total1 = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `aes_stats` WHERE `experience` > 1"),0,0);
```

Warning: `mysql_fetch_assoc()` expects parameter `1` to be resource, boolean given in on line `33`

Вот 31-34 строка:

```
31: $w_w = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `aes_stats` WHERE `experience` > 1 ORDER 
 by `experience` DESC LIMIT 0, $total1");
32: $place = array();
33: while ($a = mysql_fetch_assoc($w_w)) {$place[$a['name']] = 
 $a['experience'];}
34: arsort($place);
```

Warning: `mysql_num_rows()` expects parameter `1` to be resource, boolean given in on line `65`

Вот 65 строка:

```
 <p> Показано на странице <span><? echo mysql_num_rows($result); ?></span> </p>
```

Warning: `mysql_num_rows()` expects parameter `1` to be resource, boolean given in on line `93`

Вот строка php скрипт связанный с 93 строкой:

```
 <?php
$name_array = $names;
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{       $num++;
        $my_place = null; $ii = 1;foreach ($place as $key=>$val) {if ($key == $row['name']) {$my_place = $ii; break;}$ii++;}
        echo '<tr>
        <td><center><span title="Был в сети: '.substr($row['lastJoin'], 5, 14).'" class="label label-place">'.$num.'</center></td></td>
        <td>';


        if($bestplayers=='1' and $sort=='experience' and $descasc=='ASC'){
             if($num==1){ echo '<img src="main/img/cup1.png"/ title="Первое место"> ';}
             elseif($num==2){ echo '<img src="main/img/cup2.png" title="Второе место"/> ';}
             elseif($num==3){ echo '<img src="main/img/cup3.png" title="Третье место"/> ';}
        } 

            echo '<span class="name">'.$row['name'].'</span>';



        echo'</div></td>
        <td title="Следующее звание: '.$name_array[$row['level']+1].'"><span title="Следующее звание: '.$name_array[$row['level']+1].'" class="label label-zvanie"><span class="nick-name">'.$name_array[$row['level']].'</span></span></td>
        <td height="16" align="center"><span title="Бонусы игрока" class="label label-xp">'.$row['bonus'].'</span></td>
        <td height="16" align="center"><span title="Опыт игрока" class="label label-xp">'.$row['experience'].'</span></td>
        </tr>';
  }
  }
 ?>
```

---

P.S Для кого-то это может показаться дубликатом- это так и есть, но я пытаясь исправить данный скрипт сломал свой сайт и ничего больше, потому прошу помощи.

Answer (score 0):

- mysql - данное расширение устарело, не стоит им пользоваться(используйте например MySQLi).
- каждая из ваших ошибок означает что запрос (mysql_query) - не выполнен(вернул ошибку).

Comment: Им не то, что не стоит пользоваться, он и вовсе удален в новых версиях php.

Comment: Ну если у автора версия 5.x.x - то таки "не стоит им пользоваться", и он всё еще не удален =) А в новых версиях - да, он удален =)

Comment: Я бы даже сказал, строго не рекомендовано))

Comment: @entithat Вот с этим соглашусь на все сто % =)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков вы лучше уточняйте, что устарело именно расширение mysql для php, а не сама БД :)

Comment: @skarb пожалуй вы правы =) изменил ответ =)